# Secure Social Play 2.x / Keeping transient, unregistered (i.e. hasn't logged in yet) user in session?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I'm using Play Framework (Scala) and SecureSocial to authenticate users.

I'd like my site to allow **non**-logged-in users to browse and populate certain user data (e.g. email address) during their session.

I have a custom UserService implementation that persists logged in users to the DB (and my own `User` model object that implements the securesocial.core.Identity Trait)

I have an `UnregisteredUser` subclass which I'd like to persist in the session while the user isn't logged in.

What's the best practise for this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your particular goal is to efficiently gather the whole data relative to an unregistered user in each of your interested controller's action.
Problem: We want to retrieve a build `UnregisteredUser` directly gathering all these data in session.

First, persist the `UnregisteredUser` data whenever you want in the session using the basic Play 2's api [Sessions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaSessionFlash):

```
Ok("Welcome Guest User!").withSession(
  "email" -> "unregisteredUserEmail"  //  assuming a randomly chosen Id since not logged yet
  // many other data here
)
```

Then, you may simply write a `trait` extending your actual `SecureSocial` trait containing:

```
case class GuestRequest[A](optUnregisteredUser: Option[UnregisteredUser], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request)

def GuestAction(f: GuestRequest[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    implicit request => {
      val optUnregisteredUserEmail = session.get("currentUnregisteredUser")
      val unregisteredUser = UnregisteredUser(optUnregisteredUserEmail) 
      f(GuestRequest(optUnregisteredUser, request))
}
```

In each of your concerned controller, you would simply do:

```
def addToCard = GuestAction {
    implicit request =>
      val currentUnregisteredUser: UnregisteredUser = optUnregisteredUser.getOrElse(.....)
      //remaining instructions here
  }
```

**--------------UPDATE-------------**

Indeed, you could use `UserAwareAction` from existing `SecureSocial` trait for both User styles.
Thus, you have to override `UserAwareAction` in your trait extending SecureSocial, in order to combine features:

```
    override def UserAwareAction[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: RequestWithUser[A] => Result) = Action(p) {
        implicit request => {
          val user = for (
            authenticator <- authenticatorFromRequest;
            user <- userServices.findByUserName(authenticator.userName)
          ) yield {
            touch(authenticator)
            user
          }
          if(user.isEmpty){  //meaning user is not logged
            f(RequestWithUser(tryToBuildUnRegisteredUser, request))  //setting your unregisteredUser
          }
          else{
            f(RequestWithUser(user, request))
          }
        }
      }

 private def tryToBuildUnregisteredUser = {
    val optUnregisteredUserEmail = session.get("currentUnregisteredUser")
    optUnregisteredUserEmail match {
      case Some(e) => Some(UnregisteredUser(e)) 
      case _ => None
    }
 }
```

Of course, you are free to refactor it :)

Comment: I'm attempting to implement your solution as we speak, and keenly watching your edits as I'm quite new to Play and the additional explanation is much appreciated

Comment: I'm keen to have a user object hierarchy that has an abstract superclass containing fields like email, and subclasses for UnregisteredUser and RegisteredUser (which contains DB id for example). I'd like my controller methods to expect a User subclass, allowing me to operate equivalently with both registered and unregistered users. I'm currently using the UserAwareAction wrapped provided by SecureSocial. Is there a way to tie your GuestAction in with this, so in my controller method I get a User subclass regardless of whether it came from SecureSocial or the GuestAction session object?